# org.mule.api.MessagingException: Could not parse 'image/tiff;'

Tags: rest, http, mule, content-type, anypoint-studio

I am trying invoke (using http outbound) a REST service which returns a base64String with Content-Type `image/tiff;`. I am getting below error

---

Message               : Could not parse 'image/tiff;' (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException). Message payload is of type: String
Type                  : org.mule.api.MessagingException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
Payload               : test
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html

---

Exception stack is:
1. null (java.lang.IllegalStateException)
  com.google.common.base.Preconditions:158 (null)
2. Could not parse 'image/tiff;' (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)
  com.google.common.net.MediaType:629 (null)
3. Could not parse 'image/tiff;' (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException). Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:32 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)

---

Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:158)
    at com.google.common.net.MediaType$Tokenizer.consumeTokenIfPresent(MediaType.java:642)
    at com.google.common.net.MediaType.parse(MediaType.java:605)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.HttpResponseToMuleEvent.getEncoding(HttpResponseToMuleEvent.java:122)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.HttpResponseToMuleEvent.convert(HttpResponseToMuleEvent.java:75)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.innerProcess(DefaultHttpRequester.java:290)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.processBlocking(DefaultHttpRequester.java:186)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractNonBlockingMessageProcessor.process(AbstractNonBlockingMessageProcessor.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:85)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:102)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56)
    at org.mule.construct.DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.process(DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.java:55)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:85)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.processBlocking(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessor...

---

I am using Mule Anypoint Studio 5.3.0 and mule runtime version 3.7.2

Can someone please help on this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add the entire stack trace?

Comment: Also, if the media type is "image/tiff;" then that ";" is making it invalid, hence the error.

Comment: What do you do with the response from the HTTP outbound? What is throwing this error? We need the full stacktrace.

Comment: I have added complete trace above. Due to ';' symbol in content-type, I am getting this error. I am getting 'image/tiff;' content-type from server side. I cannot change that. I need configure something on side to accept such content-type.